# Shouldn't the `return` statement return `!` (never type)?

Tags: rust, return

Example code snippet:

```rust
fn foo() -> i32 {
    let a = return 2;
    a + 1
}
fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo());
}
```

I would expect that since `a` will never actually get assigned anything, its type should be `!`. However the compiler tells me that its type is in-fact `()` (the unit type). This struck as weird to me. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `return 42` *is* `!`:

> `break`, `continue` and `return` expressions also have type `!`. For example we are allowed to write:
>
> ```rust
> #![feature(never_type)]
> let x: ! = {
>     return 123
> };
> ```

*From https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html.*

But one of the characteristic of `!` is that it can be coerce to a value of any type:

```rust
fn foo() -> i32 {
    let a: String = return 2;
    42
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo());
}
```

This is what enables things like

```rust
let num: u32 = match get_a_number() {
    Some(num) => num,
    None => break,
};
```

(from the same page).

Both branches must have the same type. `num` is clearly `u32`, and `break` is `!`. Both can then have the same type `u32` by coercing `break` to `u32`.

This is perfectly fine because a value of type `!` can never exist, so the compiler can "convert" it to any value of any other type.

Where the confusion arises in your example is that the compiler will claim "error[E0277]: cannot add `i32` to `()`". This is probably for historical reasons. `!` didn't use to exist as such in the Rust 1.0 days. Over time it became more of a first class citizen, but some special cases were required for backwards compatibility where `!` will be treated as `()` over any other type.

Comment: Did OP have the never_type feature enabled? According to the never_type RFC, such expressions previously could be assigned the type ().

Comment: The feature only lets you make explicit use of the never type. Whether you enable it or not, the behavior, and error message, is the same in that case, for backward compatibility.

Comment: OK, I understand.